# Modifying the text in a PDF document

Tags: itext

I am putting a single line of info to the end of first page of a PDF document by using PdfStamper class. Now I need to update that info periodically. How can I modify the text I stamped previously, is there a way for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this post](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Edit-text-and-images-from-PDF-td2149927.html) from Bruno Lowagie (the creator of iText) about PDF not being a word processor. In that post he talks about using forms instead to accomplish what you are looking for which is one route you can go down.

The second route, which I'd recommend, is just having two PDFs. Have your base PDF that you open, write to and save to your output PDF. When you need to update the PDF, delete the output PDF, re-open the base PDF, write your new text and save it to the output PDF again. This accomplishes your goals without having to edit anything.